# Getting a specific key from within a hashtable

Tags: c#, collections, hashtable

So I have this Hashtable

```
Hashtable Months = new Hashtable();
Months.Add(0, "JANUARY");
Months.Add(1, "FEBRUARY");
Months.Add(2, "MARCH");
Months.Add(3, "APRIL");
Months.Add(4, "MAY");
Months.Add(5, "JUNE");
Months.Add(6, "JULY");
Months.Add(7, "AUGUST");
Months.Add(8, "SEPTEMBER");
Months.Add(9, "OCTOBER");
Months.Add(10, "NOVEMBER");
Months.Add(11, "DECEMBER");
```

I would like for the user to enter a month e.g."May" the be able to retrieve index[4] from an array within my program.

```
string Month = Console.ReadLine();
```

Basically to retrieve the index from the number of the corresponding Month entered.

Comment: Why not use a ```Dictionary<int,string>()``` there is a ```TryGetValue()``` Method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
var key = Months.Keys.Cast<int>().FirstOrDefault(v => Months[v] == "MAY");
```

Note: Don't forget to include this namespace - `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Don't quite understand this but it seems like it worked, Id really appreciate a breakdown or explanation. Thank you though

Comment: For each key in the hashtable, check it's value and return the first one that matches the month (or null if not found)

Comment: @K.John: In hashtable to access the value syntax is - `YourHashTable[key]`. Here in your HashTable, key is of type `int` and value is of type `string`. So to get key which is of type `int` we need to first cast it into int and use linq's FirstOrDefault method which internally iterate thru each key and find the matching value and return its related key.

Answer (score 0):

Get elements from your `Hashtable` in `DictionaryEntry` format

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry e in Months)
{
    if ((string)e.Value == "MAY")
    {
        //get the "index" with e.Key
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform it just using a loop;

```
    public List<string> FindKeys(string value, Hashtable hashTable)
    {
        var keyList = new List<string>();
        IDictionaryEnumerator e = hashTable.GetEnumerator();
        while (e.MoveNext())
        {
            if (e.Value.ToString().Equals(value))
            {
                keyList.Add(e.Key.ToString());
            }
        }
        return keyList;
    }
```

**Usage;**

```
var items = FindKeys("MAY",Months);
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try your method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to lookup the index from the month's name, a [**`Dictionary<string, int>`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) would be more suitable. The reason why I've swapped the parameters is becuase if you only want to lookup the index, and not also the other way around, this will be much faster.

You should declare the dictionary as case-insensitive so that it detects for instance `may`, `May`, `mAy` and `MAY` as the same thing:

```
Dictionary<string, int> Months = new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Then just use its [**`TryGetValue()` method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013(v=vs.110).aspx) whenever you want to get the month index:

```
int MonthIndex = 0;
if(Months.TryGetValue(Month, out MonthIndex)) {
    //Month was correct, continue your code...
else {
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid month!");
}
```